# Circular reference breakers for JSON written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, circular-reference

I know only one, the `cycle.js` from [Crockford's JSON-JS](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), but it is recursive and appears very slow, it take 2-5 seconds to `JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(random_graph_with_30_vertices))` and hit recursion depth limit for larger graphs. Are there better non-recursive alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Cereal](https://github.com/atomizejs/cereal)

It is not recursive. The output format is less readable, but it's still actually JSON. I believe it's fairly fast, but I've not benchmarked it against cycle. It has been used in anger in a few projects. It also solves more than just cycle-detection which may or may not be to your liking.